# port aliasing in web applications

Tags: httpd.conf

Can we alias a port number to a meaningful name. I have configured my system to serve  a couple of static pages on different ports such as 9909, 9910, leading to addresses like 192.168.1.2:9909 and 192.168.1.2:9910. Can I serve these pages with httpd using 192.168.1.2/test1 and 192.168.1.2/test2 without hosting them on tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

There's two logical numbers involved in a TCP address -- the IP address and a Port.

You can map IP addresses to meaningful names via:

- DNS
- /etc/hosts
- a hostfile specified in the HOSTALIASES environment variable

As for mapping ports to meaningful names, you're out of luck.
"192.168.1.2/test1" is most likely an HTTP address where /test1 is the path and the port is the implicit 80. It's the same as `192.168.1.2:80/test`. There are no port aliases involved in that.

If you want to get around that, I wrote a [little script](https://github.com/pjump/port_string) that unambiguously maps 3-letter strings to port numbers within the “registered” port range (1024–49151).
Your programs and libraries will still expect a numerical port, but you can use the script to input an alphabetical one and have it translate to a number.

To get longer aliases, you'd need a centralized naming service (like DNS is for IP addresses).

In any case, you can definitely start a server on `localhost:80` and map its `/test1` to proxy to `localhost:[some_port]`.